# Undefined behaviour with memcpy

Tags: c

I am copying the string using memcpy

```
 function(uint8 *data)
   {
      uint8 buffer[9];
      uint8 i = 0;
      /*some long calculation and segregation of data*/
      i = 7;
      memset(buffer, 0, 9);
      memcpy(buffer, &data[i], 8);
      printf(Buffer "%s\n", buffer);
      printf(data "%s\n", &data[i]);
    }
```

the result i am getting is

```
buffer 00 A1 Ef 45 87 E0 00 12
data   F1 A1 Ef 45 87 E0 00 12
```

First character is giving 00 instead of F1. Please some one help me to fix this simple problem

Comment: `printf(Buffer "%s\n", buffer);` -- what is `Buffer`? And did you really meant to print your *binary* buffer as a text string, using `%s`?

Answer (score 5):

`memcpy` expects pointers to buffers:

```
void * memcpy ( void * destination, const void * source, size_t num );
```

Your source is a double pointer, I think what you want is:

```
memcpy(buffer, data, 8); //since data is the pointer to your actual data
```

And as @TripeHound pointed out:

```
printf(data "%s\n", data); // not &data
```

is what you need.

Comment: And probably the same in the printf.

Comment: But i want to copy from element 8. I mean from data[7]

Comment: @user3532284: Then you need to advance your `data` pointer. Something like `memcpy(buffer, data+2, 8)`. And pay attention to the `sizes` of the _source_ and _destination_ buffers.

Comment: let me tell one thing also, some times it copies correctly